# installation error with php 5.6 and phpdbg

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-5.6, phpdbg

I have been trying to install the new PHP 5.6 on Mac OS using HomeBrew. I have no problem but when I try to get it installed using --with-phpdbg it fails with the error:

```
sapi/phpdbg/phpdbg.c:1498:2: error: expected identifier or '('
    if (cleaning || remote) {
    ^
```

I tried to reinstall homebrew and php a few times but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Just for completeness: that bug had been fixed a day later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bug of: PHP 5.6 with phpdbg on Mac OS, has described here:

A workaround waiting a fix, can be found here:

https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/13/debug-php-code-with-php-5-dot-6-and-phpdbg/

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks! The suggested fix in the [post](https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/13/debug-php-code-with-php-5-dot-6-and-phpdbg/#error) worked.